# Simple event emitter

Tags: python, python-2.x, event-handling

I have written a simple event emitter in Python, which allows subscribing to events and emitting events (along with monitoring events too). I'm rather new to Python, and would like some feedback on the overall style of my code (I tried to follow PEP 0008) as well as how it works.

```
import inspect

_DEFAULT = object()


class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, name, properties={}, cancellable=False, read_only=False,
                 monitor=False):
        self._name = name
        self._properties = properties
        self._cancellable = cancellable
        self._read_only = read_only
        self._monitor = monitor

        self._cancelled = False

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def get(self, key, default=_DEFAULT):
        if key not in self and default == _DEFAULT:
            raise KeyError(key)

        return self._properties[key] if key in self else default

    @property
    def cancellable(self):
        return self._cancellable

    @property
    def cancelled(self):
        return self._cancelled

    @property
    def read_only(self):
        return self._read_only

    @property
    def monitor(self):
        return self._monitor

    def _enforce_read_only(self):
        if self._read_only:
            raise RuntimeError('event is read only')

        if self._monitor:
            raise RuntimeError('event is monitor only')

    def set(self, key, value):
        self._enforce_read_only()

        if key not in self:
            raise KeyError(key)

        self._properties[key] = value

    @cancelled.setter
    def cancelled(self, cancelled):
        self._enforce_read_only()

        if not self.cancellable:
            raise RuntimeError('event is not cancellable')

        self._cancelled = cancelled

    def cancel(self):
        self.cancelled = True

    def make_read_only(self):
        return Event(self._name, self._properties, self._cancellable, True,
                     self._monitor)

    def make_monitor(self):
        return Event(self._name, self._properties, self._cancellable,
                     self._read_only, True)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self._properties


class EventEmitter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._monitors = {}
        self._listeners = {}

    def _emit(self, listeners, event):
        name = str(event.name)

        if name in listeners:
            for listener in listeners[name]:
                listener(event)

    def emit_event(self, event):
        self._emit(self._monitors, event.make_monitor())
        self._emit(self._listeners, event)

        return event

    def emit(self, name, properties={}, cancellable=False, read_only=False,
             monitor=False):
        return self.emit_event(Event(str(name), properties, cancellable,
                                     read_only, monitor))

    def _check_func(self, func):
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
        argcount = len(argspec.args)
        bound = hasattr(func, '__self__') and func.__self__ is not None

        if bound:
            if argcount != 2:
                raise TypeError('func {0} must accept 2 arguments, not {1}'
                                .format(func.__name__, argcount))
        elif argcount != 1:
            raise TypeError('func {0} must accept 1 argument, not {1}'.format(
                            func.__name__, argcount))

    def _listen(self, listeners, name, func):
        self._check_func(func)

        name = str(name)

        if name not in listeners:
            listeners[name] = []

        listeners[name].append(func)

    def monitor(self, name, *funcs):
        for func in funcs:
            self._listen(self._monitors, name, func)

    def on(self, name, *funcs):
        for func in funcs:
            self._listen(self._listeners, name, func)
```

There are a few things I personally don't feel comfortable with in this code, however I am not sure of the best ways to tackle them.

- `EventEmitter._check_func` looks a bit hacky to me, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to handle bound methods.
- `EventEmitter.emit`: Would it be better converting name to a string inside `Event.__init__` so that we can be sure it's a string? Because currently it's converted to a string in both `emit` and `_emit` (stringified in `_emit` in case an event is provided to `emit_event` that does not have a name that is a string).
- `Event.make_read_only` / `Event.make_monitor`: I don't like how I have to explicitly provide very variable from the current event to the new one, as I have to update both methods if the signature of `Event.__init__` changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> EventEmitter.emit: Would it be better converting name to a string inside Event.**init** so that we can be sure it's a string? Because currently it's converted to a string in both emit and _emit (stringified in _emit in case an event is provided to emit_event that does not have a name that is a string).

*Yes*. Your `init`should handle this both to avoid coercing as strings later, but also because if `event.name` isn't a string, that should be logged as an error when the `Event` is created, not when trying to call on one of its attributes. Generally you should validate variables when they're being set, not when called on.

Also you should really include [docstrings here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), as your current code isn't self explanatory so it's hard to parse without some explanation at least on the class level.